# Window appearing but unable to draw to it with OpenGL

Tags: c++, opengl, glfw, glew

I am working through a basic OpenGL course on udemy and am having trouble getting it started. I am able to get the window to display, but it is just black and will crash a few seconds later saying:

"*Exception thrown at 0x55334515 (ig11icd32.dll) in OpenGLCourseApp.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation writing location 0x078C0000.*" - something to do with symbols I think?

I saw that someone had a similar issue before that was solved by updating the graphics card drivers. I am using the built-in Intel Iris Plus graphics on a Surface Pro 7 with the most up to date driver (25.20.100.7101). The processor claims to have support for OpenGL 4.5. I have tried both 32 and 64 bit setups during troubleshooting with no difference. I'm not sure if I am doing something wrong with the setup or if I will need to use a machine with a more robust graphics processor to finish the course.

The most recent GLEW and GLFW libraries are being used.

Some PC specs:

- Intel Core i5-1035G4
- 8GB RAM
- Windows 10 Home
- Intel Iris Plus Graphics
- Visual Studio 2019

For reference, here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <GL\glew.h>
#include <GLFW\glfw3.h>

const GLint WIDTH = 800, HEIGHT = 600;

int main() 
{
    if (!glfwInit()) 
    {
        printf("GLFW INITIALIZATION FAILED!");
        glfwTerminate();
        return 1;
    }
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MAJOR, 3);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MINOR, 3);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_PROFILE, GLFW_OPENGL_CORE_PROFILE); 
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_FORWARD_COMPAT, GL_TRUE);

    GLFWwindow *mainWindow = glfwCreateWindow(WIDTH, HEIGHT, "Test Window", NULL, NULL);
    if (!mainWindow) 
    {
        printf("GLFW WINDOW CREATION FAILED!");
        glfwTerminate();
        return 1;
    }

    int bufferWidth, bufferHeight;
    glfwGetFramebufferSize(mainWindow, &bufferWidth, &bufferHeight); 

    glfwMakeContextCurrent(mainWindow);

    glewExperimental = GL_TRUE;

    if (glewInit() != GLEW_OK) 
    {
        printf("GLEW INITIALIZATION FAILED!");
        glfwDestroyWindow(mainWindow);
        glfwTerminate();
        return 1;
    }

    glViewport(0, 0, bufferWidth, bufferHeight);

    while (!glfwWindowShouldClose(mainWindow)) 
    {
        glfwPollEvents();

        glClearColor(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

        glfwSwapBuffers(mainWindow);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Any guidance for a newbie hobbyist would be appreciated!

Comment: I don't understand why someone downvoted the question. It contains a [mcve] (well the used compiler and options are missing, but that's something that can be asked for)  and a problem description. And such errors are hard to track down, so I don't understand what else the downvoter expected to be in the question.

Comment: Run in the debugger.  Use __step-over__ to find the line that fails. Update the question with what you find.

Comment: This lacks a backtrace. Any code after the place it segfaults is not part of a [mcve]. I also see many calls that don't have any error handling.BTW: "unable to draw to it" is a bad description for a segfault. Stick to observations instead of interpretations rather. That said, take the [tour] and read [ask], just to avoid a few pitfalls (your question is rather fine though).

Comment: The code works fine (Windows 10, Visual Studio 2019). So it is either an issue related to the OpenGL driver or one of the libraries. Do you use the most recent [glfw](https://www.glfw.org/) and [glew](http://glew.sourceforge.net/) library?

Comment: BTW: You could try to compile on your machine an run on a different one. If it works there, that doesn't mean your code is okay, it may just mean that you're doing something the graphic adapter doesn't support, which brings me back to the lack of error checking...

Comment: I was able to compile and run this on Windows 7 (using Visual Studio 2019), I get a window with a red background.